# How to get url parameters on AngularJs Controller?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, parameters

I'm trying to grab the parameter in my address bar, but I keep getting undefined. "Uncaught ReferenceError: $location is not defined"

This is the example path:
http://localhost:3000/list_view?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=91001&commit=Search

I have this on my app.js

```
(function() {
    "use strict";
    angular.module("app", []);
}());
```

I have this on my spaceListingCtrl.js

```
(function(){
    "use Strict"
    angular.module("app").controller("spaceListingCtrl", function($scope, $http, $location){

        $scope.spaceListings = [];
        $scope.setup = function(){
            $http.get("/api/v1/space_listings.json").then(function(response){
                $scope.spaceListings = response.data;
                $location.search();
            });
        }

        window.$scope = $scope;
    });
})();
```

I saw in some site they use

```
window.location.search.split('&')
```

How do you do this Angular?

Comment: Can you give us the demo link?

Comment: It is in my localhost still.

Comment: You can use codepen.io to demo it :)